# Excel Ten Pin Bowling Calculator

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an Excel scoring template for Ten Pin Bowling. It currently works but it's not the best way of doing it I imagine.

*Amended original question*

I have the below code to work out the scores of one game of Ten Pin Bowling. I have one row of data for the scores and output the total score for each frame to one cell and a running total to another.

The below works in some scenarios but fails when dealing with spares. I cant seem to seperate the spares and Strikes logic so it currently adds the next two throws instead of just one.

```
'C5=Frame 1 Throw 1 - 'E5=Frame 2 Throw 1 - 'G5=Frame 3 Throw 1 -   'F5=Frame 2 Throw 2=IF(OR(C5="X",D5="\"),10+ 'Checks if 1st throw of F1 is a Strike or if 2nd throw of F1 is a Spare. IF either True returns 10 and adds to next calculation.
    IF(E5="X",10,E5)+ 'Checks if 1st throw of F2 is a Strike, returns 10 if true or the value of the throw if false. Previous score is added to this value.
            IF(G5="X",10, 'Checks if 1st throw of F3 is a Strike, returns 10 if true. 
                    IF(AND(G5<>"X",E5="X"),G5,F5)) 'Checks if F3 1st throw isnt a strike and if F2 throw 1 was a strike. If true returns the value of the 
                                                    'F3 1st throw. If false returns the value of F2 throw 2.
                        ,C5+D5)'If first frame has no strike or sprare simply adds up the value of throws 1 and 2.
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: This is something I've experimented with a little and have always thought of doing a VBA version, just haven't gotten around to it. However, I did make one where the scoring is done entirely in worksheet functions. I may have made it way more complicated then it needs to be, but you can look at it and see if it gives you any ideas. I tried to include logic for entering S for splits and F for foul which made the formulas get complicated. Also, I use "/" for spares instead of "\". Here is a link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5d7hakgFRdWeVgzTkZHQUUzSFk

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will have a look at how you have done this and see if it can give me some ideas.

Comment: I have revisted this and added more logic to the formulas and I am trying to calculate the score in one cell. Edited original post with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use SUMIF. You declare the search-range and the sum range. For example A:A contains a, b, c and B:B contains 1, 2, 3 etc. 
SUMIF(A:A; "a", B:B) will return 1. There is also a function with more than one search-criteria

See here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B